# Buying itunes gift card for friend in NL

Tags: itunes, gift

I have a friend's birthday who lives in the Netherlands (I live in the UK). Is there any way I can buy a gift card from the netherlands that will send to them? Googling seems to throw up a lot of sites - not many of which seem trustworthy. Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can buy them directly from Apple and have it either [shipped](http://store.apple.com/us/browse/home/giftcards/itunes/gallery?mco=MTM3NDc0MTQ) or [emailed](https://buy.itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZFinance.woa/wa/buyLandingPage) to them.