# How to buy a gift card from a German store for a Russian store?

Tags: itunes, ios-appstore, gift

Links from [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/226993/buying-itunes-gift-card-for-friend-in-nl) redirect me to my iTunes where I can buy gift cards but there show a note "Redeemable in German store only". The same story if searching for the answer on apple.com/ru/... .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gift cards can only be redeemed in the same country/region that it was purchased. You can't redeem gift cards outside the country or region.

According to [this Apple Support page:](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT201195#differentcountry)

> If you're trying to redeem an App Store & iTunes Gift Card or Apple
>   Music Gift Card that was purchased in a different country or region,
>   make sure that you're redeeming it in the iTunes Store for the same
>   country or region. You can't redeem cards outside of the country or
>   region of purchase.

Comment: @user3439894 edited